# IIS refreshing after modify App.config

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins

I've got a specific problem with C# (particulary Selenium) and Jenkins.

I have a build step in Jenkins that :
  1) Copy a specific web.config in my project.
  2) Execute a TestMethod in my project ("mstest /testcontainer:DLL /test:Mytest")

But when we modify the App.config (step 1), IIS "refresh" the project. And the step 2 failed because the page must be reload.

I tried to put sleep command between this 2 steps, but when nodody tries to access to the application, it cannot reload alone apparently...

So can I reload my page between step 1 and 2 with bash command line (or other)?

Comment: By design editing web.config causes the AppPool to restart. IMHO having a procedure that alter a web.config is bad design. Anyway, you can disable the behaviour by editing `YOUR_APP_POOL -> Advanced Options -> Recycling -> Disable recycling for configuration changes to true`, but probably the step 2 will need the new configurations to be loaded (just guessing)

Comment: What the page load does is causing the AppPool to recycle, you can do that by command line using `appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name: APP_POOL_NAME`

Comment: Modification on web.config triggers ASP.NET runtime to reload the whole app. You have to adapt to that and revise your test script.